# Trying to get this query to run and I am having no luck

Tags: php

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=Foobar user=foo password=bar");

$query = 'SELECT * FROM kittens';

$result = pg_query($query);

while($line = pg_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ['userid'];
}
```

I am using NginX, Portgresql and cakePHP the only results I get on screen is ArayArrayArrayArray
Can give more information if needed, thanks

Comment: Why are you using a PHP Framework (CakePHP) after all? one of the main purposes on using a framework is exactly NOT to use plain SQL queries.

Comment: I edited the tags and changed CakePHP to php as this has nothing to do with CakePHP and very likely not even nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
echo ['userid'];
```

might work better as:

```
echo $line['userid'];
```

After seeing your edit, you can also try:

print_r($line);

which will print the array instead of just 'Array'

Comment: Ahhh yer I see how it works now, thanks very much, it seems CakePHP isn't working at all however we have normal PHP working!!